# Issue with using and ODBC/MySql

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, odbc, connection-pooling

So this is my sample code for an attempt to use using (for Connection Pooling) in C#. Right now I think it's giving me an error due to not being in a method. However, is there a way to get around this?

```
<% @Page Language="C#" %>
<% @Import Namespace="System.Data.Odbc" %>
<% @Import Namespace="System.Web.Configuration" %>

<script language="C#" runat="server">
string conString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cheese"].ConnectionString;
using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(conString)) {
    con.Open();
    using (OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand("SELECT pies FROM ducks WHERE isapie = nope", con)) {
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@var", paramWord);
        using (OdbcDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader()) {
            while (reader.Read()) {
                Response.Write(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
</script>
```

Right now the line giving the error is:

```
Line 8:     using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(conString)) {
```

And the error in question is:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1519: Invalid token 'using' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
```

I am trying to keep my code minimalistic, easy to edit, etc. and so I'd like to avoid having unnecessary classes, methods, etc. simply for the sake of having them.

Comment: First, you will need to move the closing brace after `con.Open();` down to after `con.Close();`. You are disposing the connection before you've finished with it.

Comment: Done and edited. Same error on the same line though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues; the first one is that you don't have your code defined within a method. For this to work, you need to put it inside Page_Load for example:

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">

void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    string conString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cheese"].ConnectionString;
    using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(conString)) {
    con.Open();

    using (OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand("SELECT pies FROM ducks WHERE isapie = nope", con)) {
         com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@var", paramWord);
         using (OdbcDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader()) {
          while (reader.Read()) 
             Response.Write(reader.GetString(0));
         }//end using reader
     }//end using ODBCCommand
  }//end using ODBCConnection
}//page_load
</script>
```

The second problem is that you use `using` to open the connection and you attempt to use the connection object below the closing `}`. By the the time you reach the second `using` where you instantiate your OdbcCommand the connection is already disposed. you need to do something like this instead:

```
void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
string conString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cheese"].ConnectionString;
using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(conString)) {
    con.Open();

using (OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand("SELECT pies FROM ducks WHERE isapie = nope", con)) {
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@var", paramWord);
    using (OdbcDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader()) {
        while (reader.Read()) {
            Response.Write(reader.GetString(0));
        }
    }
 }
 con.Close();
 }
}
```

Finally, you should use a gridview or something of the sort to bind this data as opposed to writing to the `Response Stream` the way you are doing it. Assuming you have a Gridview in your page; you could perfectly do this:

```
gridView.DataSource=com.ExecuteReader();
gridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: Ah, I'm not big on having .Net generate my code for me... I find it hardly knows what it's doing half the time and I do care a lot about XHTML compliance and need to do nifty JavaScript things (which is more my realm of expertise). Thank you though, your explanation was very helpful and you were quite polite about it! I haven't done C# in years and some people have been very rude when I ask questions.